# Periodic batch mixed with streaming -- toy problem illustrating my problem

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

This is a made up toy example to try to get help on the harder parts of my problem. Let's say I have sales data that I'm getting from a Kafka stream:

```
...
Period: 5, SalesPersonId: 78, Sale: TRUE, Timestamp: ...,  
Period: 5, SalesPersonId: 43, Sale: FALSE, Timestamp: ...,  
Period: 5, SalesPersonId: 33, Sale: TRUE, Timestamp: ...,  
...
```

Each row represents a particular salesperson's sale opportunity (during a particular period).

Here's how periods work: periods last roughly 2-3 weeks. But, the periods aren't under my control; they are assigned already when they arrive in the stream. In the transition between periods I might still be receiving data from the last period for a day or two (a sales location in Japan might still be on the old period for a bit, for example). Someone on the Beam chat suggested I could use session windows for this case if I just include the period in my key and make the gap duration 2 days, roughly. Seems like that would work.

It's clear to me how to do stuff like: total number of sales opportunities per period, average sales rate per salesperson per period, etc. For example, call the PCollection resulting from the following query **A**:

```
SELECT
    period,
    salesPersonId,
    COUNT(*) as totalSalesOpportunities,
    COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE sale) as totalSales,  
    ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE SALE)/COUNT(*),2) as salesRate  
FROM stream  
GROUP BY period, salesPersonId
```

My requirement is more complicated than that. Let's say our company has a hypothesis that salespeople who have more sales opportunities during a period will have a better sales rate. Perhaps total sales opportunities is an indication of motivation, or the extra opportunities give more practice trying to sell whatever product is being sold that period. So, the company wants this statistic:

**What is the aggregate salesrate of salespeople who are in the 90th or higher percentile for sales opportunities in this period (so far)? 10th or lower percentile?** I.e.,

`(TOTAL SALES MADE BY PEOPLE WITH 90%+ SALES OPPORTUNITIES)/(TOTAL SALES OPPORTUNITIES BY PEOPLE WITH 90%+ SALES OPPORTUNITIES)`

Of course, early on in a period the 90th percentile might only be 3 opportunities. But, over time the distribution will spread out and it might be 40 opportunities. It's okay, then, if this statistic is updated, say, hourly.

As far as I can tell I would need to do the following, call it **B**:

`Rekey A, apply ApproximateQuantiles, feed it back to filter A, reaggregate A.`

But, I don't think that could be done incrementally. So how do I express "keep doing A incrementally, but do B as a batch operation every hour"?

Or, is there a better way to handle this situation with Beam?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, You need 2 type of aggregation on same data.

1. Incremental Aggregation for A
2. Hourly Aggregation for B

One thing to note here is that you can not make A depend on B ad B depend on A as this creates a cycle in your pipeline graph.

You can start with PC1 which contains your original input stream.

PC2: PC1 -> Do A'(Which is same as A) -> Do B

PC3: PC1 -> Do A with PC2 as side input.

You can read more about side input [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs)